# Symfony upload file - store file between request

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

is there some way to transfer object UploadedFile to next request?
I am trying to do this:

- Step 1 - Upload csv file
- Step 2 - Open that file and print data back to user for check
- Step 3 - Parse a file and store data

I would like to transfer file between step 2 and 3.  without store. Is 
What is a the correct procedure to do this?

Thanks for answers

Comment: no, PHP is stateless, you can't store a file without storing it....